# How can i submit action link from Form using Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How can achieve this in angular 7? how can submit this post action url in angular?

```
<form method="post" action="https://securegw- 
stage.paytm.in/order/process" name="paytm">
     <table border="1">
        <tbody>
           <input type="hidden" name="MID" value="YOUR_MID_HERE">
        </tbody>
     </table>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        document.paytm.submit();
     </script>
  </form>
```

Please help...
thank you...

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Send the form when page is loaded ?

Comment: yes, i want to call submit event on page load

Comment: I think you can use ReactiveForm provided by angular https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: how can i call this "<script type="text/javascript">
        document.paytm.submit();
     </script>" in angular using Reactive forms?

Comment: You cannot do that. You should not try to access dom element from angular context outside of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with selecting form in Component then call submit on nativeElement ?

```
@ViewChild('paytmForm', { read: ElementRef }) paytmForm: ElementRef; 

ngAfterContentInit() {
   this.paytmForm.nativeElement.submit()
}
```

In template add `#paytmForm` on form element

```
<form method="post" action="https://securegw- 
stage.paytm.in/order/process" name="paytm" #paytmForm >
...
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much... i already tried this but didn't worked because i was called "this.paytmForm.nativeElement.submit()" just after dynamic form creation... now i tried dynamic form on page load then i got this... Thank you so much "ngAfterContentInit()"

Comment: You should read more about angular component lifecycle : https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks
It will help you for a lot of things ;)

Comment: how can done this with reactive forms? please tell me if you have any idea?

Comment: Not sure you can do exactly what you want. What you can do is get form value then  send those values with httpClient

Comment: but i tried using httpclient also but it is not responding as submit()

Comment: That's because the content type is not the same between form and httpclient.
Form encode body as application/x-www-form-urlencoded while httclient send body as json by default.
So if you want send json you need to change your backend controller or tells angular to send as form (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605542/angular-6-http-post-request-with-x-www-form-urlencoded-data/51605684)

Comment: thank you... it'll redirect as same as post method?