# HOW/CAN I make an RxJs POST request sending my payload by making use of x-www-form-urlencoded in the body of the request

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to set up a 3rd party payment provider, and it would seem that they do not accept the payload to be send to them in a the Body as JSON.

It seems I must send my request with payload setup in a x-www-form-urlencoded body(I think. Newb.)

**The working example I got from the payment provider is setup as per below image in Postman:**

[image: Postman Working Example]

**Here is my current RxJs POST method, sending the payload in the body as JSON:**

```
data = {
    entityId: '8a8294174e735d0c014e78cf26461790',
    amount: '92.00',
    currency: 'ZAR',
    paymentType: 'DB'
};

prepareCheckout(): Observable<any> {

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    Authorization: this.bearer
  })
};

return this.http
  .post(this.apiUrl, this.data, httpOptions)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

How can I modify this POST request to comply to what is happening in Postman?

Comment: This is actually using Angular’s HTTP request implementation, correct? Then you should probably be using `HttpParams` to encode your data object into the necessary query string format. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54634342/10955263

Comment: @04FS Jip, I am using Angular. Thanks for the link. Checking it out.